# Cypress assertions: what is the behavior when `cy.get()` matches multiple elements?

Tags: html, testing, cypress

I am having trouble finding documentation that explains how Cypress assertions work when `cy.get()` matches multiple elements.  For example:

Markup:

```
<div>
  <button>one</button>
  <button class='green'>two</button>
  <button disabled>three</button>
</div>
```

Test:

```
cy.get('button').should('be.disabled');
```

Does Cypress assert that:

1. the first matched element passes?
2. all matched elements pass?
3. at least one of the elements pass?

From experience I am guessing it is option 3 but I haven't been able to find this explicitly addressed in the documentation.

Whereas

```
cy.get('button').click();
```

clicks... only the first button?  All of them?

On the assertions, I'm afraid we are unintentionally writing tests that pass in cases where our selector incidentally matches more than one element, and one of those elements happens to match the assertion criteria.

Obviously this *can* be avoided with well written selectors, or use of `.first()` or `.last()` if we expect to return more than one, or `.each()` if we want to explicitly assert multiple elements.  I'm primarily looking for confirmation on what the behavior is so I understand how Cypress works in these situations where multiple elements are selected (intentionally or otherwise.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the assertions in `.should()`, I *believe* that Cypress operates in the same way that [ChaiJQuery](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery) operates, which switches between validating the first element meets the criteria, or that *any* element meets the criteria.

For example, [attr](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery#attrname-value)

> Assert that the first element of the selection has the given attribute, using .attr(). Optionally, assert a particular value as well. The return value is available for chaining.

vs. [hidden](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery#hidden)

> Assert that at least one element of the selection is selected, using .is(':selected').

For other Cypress commands, you'll have to investigate their behaviors. [For an example with `cy.click()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Click-all-elements-with-id-starting-with-btn):

> By default, Cypress will error if you're trying to click multiple elements. By passing `{ multiple: true }` Cypress will iteratively apply the click to each element and will also log to the Command Log multiple times.

So, the tl;dr answer is each chained command behaves differently.

Comment: Hey thank you!  I guess that explains why I couldn't find this detail in the Cypress documentation.  I'm sure I read it at some point but I forgot that the assertions are implemented in a third party library.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the assertion.

There is an example here [Multiple elements](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/commands/assertions.html#multiple-elements)

```html
<ul id="greetings">
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Aloha</li>
</ul>
```

```js
cy.get('#greetings li')
  .should('include.text', 'Hello')
  .and('include.text', 'Hi')               // "include" allows any one 
  .and('include.text', 'Aloha')
  .and('have.text', 'HelloHiAloha')
  // let's check the jQuery text() method
  .invoke('text')
  .should('equal', 'HelloHiAloha')         // must match all 3 texts
```

The `include.text` will apply to any one of the elements, but the `have.text` applies to all elements combined.

```js
cy.get('#greetings li')
  .should('have.text', 'Hello')    // fails
```

---

What about `be.disabled`?

From [chai-jquery](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-jquery/)

> **disabled**
>
> Assert that **at least one element of the selection** is disabled, using .is(':disabled').

As an opposite example,

> **attr(name[, value])**
>
> Assert that **the first element of the selection** has the given attribute, using .attr(). Optionally, assert a particular value as well. The return value is available for chaining.

In general, Cypress follows the rules set down by the library it uses, so this documentation is a good reference for your question.

Comment: Thank you - I was reading the assertions reference on Cypress but overlooked the link to chai-jquery